# How sort command column option is handled

Tags: sort

I have a file like

```
1.2.3.4
1.1.1.1
4.5.6.7
1.1.3.5
```

When I gave

```
sort -t. -k3 inp3

1.1.1.1
1.2.3.4
1.1.3.5
4.5.6.7
```

and when I gave

```
sort -t. -k3,3 inp3
1.1.1.1
1.1.3.5
1.2.3.4
4.5.6.7
```

second and third columns differ. I could see lots of questions and answers regarding this k option. Is it correct that when I give -k3, since 3rd columns for

```
1.1.3.5
1.2.3.4
```

are same 4 th column is considered.

What difference does it make when give

```
sort -n -t. -k3 inp3
```

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `-k` is:

```
    -k field_start[type][,field_end[type]]
```

If the final field is omitted, all fields from the starting field are used. In any case, the secondary fields are used for tie-breaking in order.

So when you do `-k3`, fields 3 and 4 are used for sorting, with 4 for tie-breaking. With `-k3,3`, only field 3 is used - the others are ignored. So you are correct in your conclusion.

`-n` specified by itself means that all fields be treated as numbers and sorted accordingly. Alphabetically (rather, lexicographically), `2` comes after `102`, numerically it's the other way around. See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/sort.1posix.html) to know what it means when a field is treated as a number.

Comment: For the row `1.2.3.4`, I changed it to `1.2.3.44`. But even if i used -n option `1.2.3.44` comes before `1.2.3.5`!

Comment: @user3539 with `-k3` or `-k3,3`?

Comment: both options give the same result

Comment: @user3539 :facepalm: You're using `.` as a separator, but, as the manpage explains, `.` is a valid character in a number - it is the decimal separator depending on the locale. You're comparing `3.44` to `3.5`. Looks like field-splitting is done on the fly.

Comment: Any idea how to handle this situation?

Comment: @user3539 Depends. If there's a character you know for sure is not going to be in the file (say, `:` or `|`), try replacing them: `tr . :  | sort -n -t: -k3 | tr : .`.

Comment: @muru I am late to this post but, I think where you state "...`-k3,3`, only field 3 is used...", is not correct, When I set the 4th column to be identical when the field 3 is identical, it seems the beginning columns (1 & 2) are used.